# Как вставить progressbar в таблицу?

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица и есть progressbar
Мне необходимо как то бар поставить под thead просто визуально, без обработки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код таблицы

```
<table style="max-width: 1200px;min-width: 320px;width: 100%;text-align: center;margin: 0px auto;" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-responsive">
<thead style="background: #eaf9fc;">
<tr class="mmm">
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Откуда</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Куда</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Туда-Обратно</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Старая цена</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Новая цена</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Скидка</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Ссылка</th>

</tr>
</thead>


<tbody id="auto_price"></tbody>
</table>
```

А вот бар

```
<div class="progress-bar blue">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Что только не делал, или встает над всей таблицей как на скрине или же в одну ячейку таблицы. Сайт aviareysi.ru - если нужен. Спасибо

td формируются скриптом

```
var main_tpl = '<tr style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.49);">'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Откуда">' + From + '</td>'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Куда">' + To + '</td>'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Дата">' + datew + '</td>'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Старая цена">' + price_old + '</td>'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Новая цена">' + price_new + '</td>'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Скидка">' + percentage + '</td>'
                +'<td style="background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">' + title_link + '</td>'
                +'</tr>';
```

Прошу помощи!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65548/discussion-on-question-by-arcadiy---progressbar--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого достаточно вставить еще одну строчку в `thead` с ячейкой, у которой `colspan` взят с допустимым запасом. Поскольку в страницах редко встречаются таблицы больше 40 ячеек, то условия `colspan="100"` будет вполне достаточно.

```
<thead style="background: #eaf9fc;">
...
<tr>
   <td colspan="100">
       <div class="progress-bar blue">
           <span></span>
       </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Полный пример:

```css
.progress-bar {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar.blue > span {
    background-color: #5dbbf2;
}

.progress-bar > span {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: linear-gradient(center bottom, white 40%, #54f054 69%);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table style="max-width: 1200px;min-width: 320px;width: 100%;text-align: center;margin: 0px auto;" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-responsive">
<thead style="background: #eaf9fc;">
<tr class="mmm">
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Откуда</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Куда</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Туда-Обратно</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Старая цена</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Новая цена</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Скидка</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Ссылка</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="100">
       <div class="progress-bar blue">
           <span></span>
       </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="auto_price">
    <tr style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">Москва (Россия)</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">Апиа (Самоа)</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">30.12 - 14.01</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">213284</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">140839</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">34%</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px;background:rgba(248, 203, 227, 0.22);font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a style="padding:3px;text-decoration:none;background: #00a4f7;box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #000000;color: #fff;" title="Посмотреть авиабилет undefined undefined undefinedundefined" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Перейти</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое